# Return several rows in python from Excel Table

Tags: python, excel, export

I was wondering if I can return several rows of an excel sheet that where some columns consist of a unique string. And then I want to export them into a CSV.

I was considering openpyxl but am not getting too far.

If my Excel looks like that:

[Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FhrOd.png)

I would e.g. search for ID2 and return all rows

```
ID2,1,ping
ID2,2,pong
```

```
from openpyxl import Workbook
import openpyxl

file = "test.xlsx"
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(file, read_only=True)
ws = wb.active

for row in ws.iter_rows("A"):
    for cell in row:
        if cell.value == "ID2":
            print(ws.cell(row=cell.row, column=1,2,3).value)
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Try using pandas `pd.read_excel()` and `pd.to_csv()`, for example:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel('/file/path/excel.xslx')
df_filtered = df[df['id_column'] == 'ID1']  # returns df with only rows where 'id_column' is 'ID1'
df_filtered.to_csv('/file/path/output.csv')
```

Would export a csv with only rows where your `'id_column'` is equal to `'ID1'`.

Comment: Awesome, pandas is amazing. Thank you!